# Logback file and access spring boot configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback

How can I put into spring boot app properties logback-file.xml and logback-access.xml at the same time? And if I can, logs will write in one file, or in different?

Answer (score 0):

See the available [Spring Boot properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html).

You will find generic `logging.*` ones as well as `server.tomcat.accesslog.*` **OR** `server.jetty.accesslog.*` depending on your embedded servlet container.

Answer (score 0):

Core logs will be printed based on logback-spring.xml, and access-logs (logs written whenever someone accesses any of your API's) will be printed based on logback-access.xml.

In application.properties, use logging.* for core/server logs and server.(yourserver).accesslog.* for access logs.